# Скрытие ввода данных PHP-cli Linux

Tags: php, linux

Имеется cli-скрипт на PHP. Есть данные, которые вводятся с клавиатуры, их бы желательно скрыть, например, закрыть звездочками. На данный момент пользуюсь функцией readline:

```
$password = readline('Password: ');
```

В bash это реализуется при помощи команды read:

```
read -s var
```

Можно ли реализовать подобное пользуясь возможностями php?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187736/command-line-password-prompt-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
<?php
echo 'Password: ';
$oldStyle = shell_exec('stty -g');
shell_exec('stty -echo');
$password = rtrim(fgets(STDIN), "\n");
shell_exec('stty ' . $oldStyle);
echo "\r\n";
echo $password;
echo "\r\n";
```